# GLM Model Summary Problems

Tags: r, glm

I've run the following GLM model in R, and the summary results are not making sense. The P-values are identical and the coefficients are extremely large. Something is off, but I don't know specifically what.

```
mod.glm <- glm(factor(CloseWon) ~ days_to_close + factor(state) + number_of_times_contacted + number_of_sales_activities + factor(original_source) + average_pageviews + marketing_emails_delivered + sends_since_last_engagement, data = HSBI_train, family = binomial('logit'))

summary(mod)
```

Below is the link to the image of my output,
Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5jsQ.jpg

dput as requested:

```
dput(HSBI)
structure(list(days_to_close = c(143L, 0L, 264L, 0L, 138L, 0L, 
117L, 48L, 258L, 0L, 59L, 125L, 204L, 260L, 0L, 210L, 0L, 119L, 
0L, 286L, 29L, 0L, 56L, 0L, 0L, 92L, 92L, 94L, 38L, 223L, 284L, 
0L, 289L, 278L, 128L, 52L, 137L, 0L, 256L, 0L, 119L, 175L, 225L, 
118L, 161L, 129L, 94L, 0L, 33L, 0L, 0L, 26L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
163L, 112L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 251L, 0L, 0L, 
100L, 0L, 118L, 126L, 65L, 0L, 116L, 120L, 0L, 115L, 20L, 40L, 
0L, 77L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 184L, 0L, 268L, 0L, 49L, 128L, 
0L, 129L, 240L, 0L, 164L, 0L, 73L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 22L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 268L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 99L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
263L, 0L, 0L, 265L, 0L, 280L, 174L, 267L, 0L, 0L, 260L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 219L, 0L, 0L, 292L, 0L, 259L, 0L, 0L, 114L, 127L, 127L, 0L, 
41L, 0L, 251L, 281L, 0L, 226L, 277L, 268L, 0L, 219L, 0L, 97L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 218L, 0L, 98L, 64L, 0L, 0L, 101L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 165L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 76L, 48L, 233L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 107L, 189L, 0L, 94L, 19L, 223L, 128L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 106L, 246L, 
0L, 0L, 118L, 168L, 160L, 0L, 225L, 231L, 222L, 0L, 0L, 122L, 
0L, 37L, 236L, 246L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 70L, 0L, 123L, 264L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 264L, 0L, 41L, 296L, 124L, 198L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 58L, 156L, 
166L, 274L, 0L, 88L, 2L, 0L, 124L, 0L, 80L, 41L, 278L, 0L, 0L, 
252L, 0L, 80L, 0L, 0L), state = c("", "fl", "fl", "sj", "ga", 
"nc", "ga", "in", "ga", "ca", "va", "ca", "va", "tn", "co", "tx", 
"fl", "tn", "ca", "tn", "in", "ga", "il", "nj", "ca", "ga", "ga", 
"", "", "ga", "ga", "fl", "ga", "nc", "ga", "tx", "", "ga", "ga", 
"dc", "ny", "tn", "fl", "va", "ga", "al", "ca", "nv", "ca", "ga", 
"sc", "va", "ga", "oh", "ga", "fl", "la", "tn", "ny", "fl", "ca", 
"ca", "wa", "ny", "il", "ga", "ca", "fl", "fl", "al", "al", "fl", 
"al", "tn", "sc", "", "fl", "ga", "az", "fl", "ga", "", "ca", 
"ga", "ga", "oh", "ga", "al", "ga", "", "tx", "sc", "ga", "ny", 
"nc", "tn", "co", "oh", "al", "tx", "", "co", "ne", "ny", "fl", 
"oh", "ga", "ia", "va", "fl", "sc", "ca", "tn", "ga", "co", "ok", 
"ga", "al", "tx", "", "fl", "md", "ga", "al", "tn", "wa", "al", 
"oh", "ga", "ga", "", "pa", "oh", "al", "ny", "az", "tn", "oh", 
"ga", "tx", "ga", "tx", "tn", "va", "fl", "ga", "ga", "fl", "ny", 
"fl", "az", "ga", "ga", "tn", "ga", "", "ga", "pa", "fl", "tn", 
"al", "ga", "al", "ga", "ms", "vt", "ca", "fl", "fl", "ky", "oh", 
"wa", "fl", "wa", "ga", "az", "il", "al", "nc", "al", "nj", "tx", 
"tx", "fl", "la", "ga", "nc", "", "ga", "al", "tx", "oh", "fl", 
"tn", "tn", "fl", "ga", "ca", "", "ca", "fl", "ga", "fl", "dc", 
"md", "fl", "tx", "oh", "tx", "", "al", "tx", "fl", "tn", "tx", 
"ny", "ny", "tn", "az", "ga", "al", "tx", "sc", "tn", "tn", "ca", 
"al", "tn", "fl", "al", "tn", "ga", "ga", "ga", "fl", "pa", "tx", 
"co", "sc", "tx", "tx", "ga", "ny", "ma", "ny", "fl", "fl", "ca", 
"tn", "nv", "ga", "ga", "tx", "", "or", "", "fl", "il"), number_of_times_contacted = c(7L, 
5L, 7L, 2L, 40L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 10L, 
4L, 9L, 3L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 
4L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 12L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 31L, 
10L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 20L, 15L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 19L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 
3L, 8L, 12L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 50L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 
7L, 3L, 14L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 
7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 
10L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 4L, 1L, 
11L, 12L, 7L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 17L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 33L, 9L, 
1L, 4L, 8L, 6L, NA, 7L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 10L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 12L, 24L, 9L, 3L, 11L, 3L, 19L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 
7L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 9L, 
8L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 13L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 
1L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 11L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
6L, 6L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 21L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 21L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 
3L, 8L, 8L, 7L), number_of_sales_activities = c(8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 
61L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 
10L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 
10L, 6L, 14L, 3L, 10L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 43L, 10L, 7L, 1L, 
5L, 22L, 21L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
28L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 12L, 
1L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 98L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 17L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 
6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 
3L, 8L, 16L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 15L, 4L, 1L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 
21L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 21L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 61L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 7L, NA, 
7L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 35L, 
17L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 28L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 
3L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 20L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 12L, 
10L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 
26L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 39L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 7L), original_source = c("Direct Traffic", 
"Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Organic Search", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", "Paid Social", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Organic Search", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Organic Social", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", "Paid Social", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", 
"Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Paid Social", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Paid Social", "Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Paid Social", "Paid Social", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Organic Search", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", "Direct Traffic", 
"Direct Traffic"), average_pageviews = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), marketing_emails_delivered = c(15L, 
6L, 13L, 7L, 65L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 22L, 3L, 8L, 12L, 17L, 15L, 
2L, 18L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 20L, 10L, 12L, 11L, 14L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 
6L, 8L, 19L, 21L, 3L, 20L, 22L, 15L, 11L, 14L, 8L, 21L, 21L, 
11L, 14L, 15L, 11L, 47L, 16L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 22L, 14L, 10L, 8L, 
2L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 21L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 
21L, 15L, 2L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 16L, 8L, 3L, 16L, 17L, 2L, 16L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 44L, 19L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 12L, 7L, 9L, 22L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 21L, 5L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 21L, 10L, 9L, 
10L, 12L, 3L, 13L, 22L, 9L, 6L, 17L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 
22L, 14L, 9L, 22L, 8L, 23L, 13L, 20L, 9L, 10L, 22L, 9L, 9L, 18L, 
19L, 13L, 19L, 20L, 18L, 13L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 19L, 8L, 
3L, 13L, 24L, 15L, 28L, 24L, 22L, 4L, 19L, 31L, 15L, 9L, 2L, 
44L, 11L, 2L, 10L, 13L, 18L, 3L, 15L, 9L, 19L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 16L, 
10L, 5L, 19L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 20L, 14L, 8L, 9L, 21L, 7L, 21L, 11L, 
14L, 19L, 15L, 10L, 19L, 16L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 10L, 21L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 
15L, 16L, 2L, 11L, 21L, 11L, 22L, 16L, 16L, 9L, 8L, 21L, 21L, 
3L, 1L, 20L, 13L, 9L, 16L, 13L, 6L, 10L, 15L, 3L, 20L, 11L, 8L, 
21L, 16L, 14L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 8L, 16L, 9L, 23L, 9L, 15L, 2L, 22L, 
16L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 31L, 19L, 18L, 21L, 9L, 14L, 19L, 10L), CloseWon = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -258L
))
```

Comment: Can you just post the plaintext output of summary(mod) instead of a photograph of the screen? I can't read it.

Comment: I can copy and paste, but I just reuploaded a photo that should be readable this time

Comment: Could you attach your data? I suspect that there is very little variation in your dependent variable which could explain what you get, but this is just a guess

Comment: It's not possible to answer this given the information provided. For what it's worth I've seen very small p-values on all RHS variables with a huge sample size.

Comment: I've always used a numeric 0/1 variable on the left hand side of logistic regressions. What happens when you use CloseWon (without coercing to factor) in the formula?

Comment: Consider using `dput(<yourdata>)` to share your data. Edit your question and add the data by pasting in the output from the `dput`.

Comment: @JohnPolo dput output added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regressor `days_to_close` is problematic. Notice that you get an error on fitted probabilites numerically 0 or 1 in this simple regression.

```
> mod.glm <- glm(factor(CloseWon) ~ days_to_close, data=data,
+                family = binomial('logit'))
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

To see why this happens, note

```
> table(data$days_to_close > 0, data$CloseWon)
       
          0   1
  FALSE 124   2
  TRUE    0 132
```

So you see that independent of what value your other regressors get, CloseWon is always 0 whenvever days_to_close is greater than zero. Loosely speaking, this means that the the function you are trying to optimise gets the value of +oo. The optimisation algorithm trips on this and ends up pushing your other regression coefficients to huge values.

There are tons of papers on how to tackle perfect separation. You can start, e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression).

Comment: Thanyou. Very helpful